# How to work out the hostname that compose gives containers?

Tags: docker-compose

I have this:

```
version: '2'
services:
   go-cd-server:
       image: abc/go-server:trusted
       ports:
         - "8154:8154"
         - "8153:8153"
   go-cd-agent:
       image: abc/go-agent:trusted
       environment:
         - GO_SERVER= ????????
```

I am led to believe that there is a built in DNS server enabling me to fill in the ???? above. What will the host name of the go-cd-server container be? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `go-cd-server` as the hostname.